# RSpec test of Treetop parser output doesn't match when it should

Tags: ruby, rspec, treetop

I have this spec:

```
it 'can parse armies with only section headers' do
  list = <<-LIST
  :Core
  :Special
  :Omgg
  :Moarheaders
  LIST
  expected_output = "## Core\n## Special\n## Omgg\n## Moarheaders\n"
  parsed = @parser.parse(list)
  parsed.should_not be_nil
  parsed.transform.should be expected_output
end
```

Which produces this output:

```
expected ## Core
## Special
## Omgg
## Moarheaders
, got "## Core\n## Special\n## Omgg\n## Moarheaders\n"
```

If I remove the double quotes, I get this output:

```
expected ## Core\n## Special\n## Omgg\n## Moarheaders\n, 
got     "## Core\n## Special\n## Omgg\n## Moarheaders\n"
```

If I add quotes to my expected_output, I get this:
(`expected_output = '"## Core\n## Special\n## Omgg\n## Moarheaders\n"'`)

```
expected "## Core\n## Special\n## Omgg\n## Moarheaders\n", 
got      "## Core\n## Special\n## Omgg\n## Moarheaders\n"
```

What's going on here?

I can't get the Treetop result to evaluate the \n as newlines, and I can't get the expected_output to match regardless of what I try.

I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

`parsed.transform.should == expected_output`

`be` might use object identity instead of comparing the string values.

Comment: Ahh, can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks so much. That was the trick. :)

Comment: Well I didn't know that `be` acted that way, so I learned something too.

PS. Would you mind accepting the answer?